# How could I obtain a count from multiple colums?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL server with data of Courses, WorkingArea and Province and I want to get the count of WorkingArea for each Province and for each course.

[image]

Could you help me please?

For example, there are 2 "Desempleados" in "Almeria" for "Course A", so I want "2" as result in another column, but when I try to group by, the results are never ok...

The result should be:

| CourseName | WorkingArea | Province | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COURSE A | Desempleado | Almería | 2 |
| COURSE A | Administración Autonómica | Almería | 1 |

Comment: select coursename,workingarea,province,count(*)cntt from your_table group by coursename,workingarea,province  Have you tried this one?

Comment: @Sergey omg, I was trying to group by one or two columns but never with all the columns... It seem to be ok now wow, thank you so much

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT - _except those who are arguments tp set functions_.

Comment: Based on your statement *"I have a table in SQL server"* I have removed the tag for [[tag:mysql]]; please do not tag conflicting products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a `GROUP BY` clause. The `GROUP BY` clause is used within a `SELECT` statement to group rows into sets based on the values of one or more columns. It is often used with aggregate functions such as SUM, AVG, MAX, MIN, and COUNT to calculate summary information for each group. e.g.

```
SELECT
      coursename
    , workingarea
    , province
    , count(*) AS cnt
FROM your_table
GROUP BY
      coursename
    , workingarea
    , province
```

Comment: yes, you are correct, never try to group by all the three columns, my fault, thank you :) this works fine